# AWS Python CDK Sharing Libraries

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK inside VSCODE. My project layout is such that a single directory contains multiple top-level stacks.

I would like to be able to share code between Stacks. To be specific, it is code and not cross-stack references or resources.

For instance I have a tagging function that I want to be able share and use across all stacks

```
   def default_tag_stacks(*args: cdk.Stack):
    for stack in args:
        cdk.Tags.of(stack).add("OU", "PlatformInfrastructure")
        cdk.Tags.of(stack).add("GovernanceLevel", "Production")
        cdk.Tags.of(stack).add("Owner", "Platform")
```

My editor sees the library and picks up the import, but when running

```
cdk synth
```

I get an import error. Is there path variable or another project structure I can follow so I can share code that is not part of a particular stack?

Project structure is as follows

```
/
 lib/tagging.py
 stack-1/app.py
 stack-2/app.py
```

Imports are as such

```
from lib.tagging import tag_all_app_stacks_default
```

```
cd stack-1
cdk synth
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lib.tagging import tag_all_app_stacks_default
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

Comment: Can you please add the example of the project structure, the relevant imports, and the `cdk synth` error? Otherwise it's difficult to understand what goes wrong

Comment: Added more info.

Answer (score -1):

You should decide what is the top-level project directory for imports. If it's /, then you should have `app.py` and `cdk.json` in /, and `cdk synth` should work. Otherwise (i.e. your working directory for the project is `stack-1`), the import should be `from tagging import tag_all_app_stacks_default`. You can read more about how Python module imports work in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.